# Change focus to particular para in medium editor (github)

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, medium-editor

How to change the position of cursor to particular para in medium editor. I am able to fetch node of the target para but unable to relocate cursor. Tried `focus()` but its not working. Also tried `Editor.selectElement(`) but it highlights the whole para, didn't move the cursor. Any help on this? Just a beginner to editor. Thanks in advance

https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found out the solution for this. MediumEditor provides method for this

```
MediumEditor.selection.moveCursor(document, element, 0);
```

It doesn't works on if editor is blur (In that case you need to focus the editor first and then use this method)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using both `selectElement()` and `selection.clearSelection()` directly after each other to accomplish this.

Calling `editor.selectElement(element)` will be sure to trigger focus and all the things that need to happen when the editor regains focus.  Then calling `MediumEditor.selection.clearSelection(document)` will collapse the selection to a single cursor at the end of the paragraph.

If you wanted the cursor to be at the start of the paragraph instead of the end, just pass `true` as the 2nd argument to `clearSelection(document, true)`.

```js
editor.selectElement(element)
MediumEditor.selection.clearSelection(document)
```